# Understanding HTML form code

Tags: html, forms

i am bit confused about the code..This is login.php file..and action of the form is also in the same file.Can this happen? if,then same login form should open if user submit the form...i am making my website,where i want to use login/register form.

```
<form action="login.php" method="post" class="f-wrap-1">
    <div class="req">
       <a href="signup.php">Not Registered?</a><br />
       <a href="recoverpass.php">Forgot your Password?</a>
    </div>
    <fieldset>
      <h3>Member Login</h3>
        <label for="firstname"><b>Username:</b>
           <input id="username" name="username" type="text" class="f-name" autocomplete="on" tabindex="1" /><br />
        </label>
        <label for="password"><b>Password:</b>
           <input id="password" name="password" type="password" class="f-name" autocomplete="off" tabindex="2" /><br />
        </label>
        <label for="code"><b>Security Code:</b>
           <input id="code" name="code" type="text" class="f-name" autocomplete="off" tabindex="3" /><br />
        </label>
        <label for="code2"><b>&nbsp;</b>
           <img src="image.php?" /><br />
        </label>
        <div class="f-submit-wrap">
           <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="f-submit" tabindex="4" /><br />
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: U dont need `action` if you redirect to the same page.

Answer (score 4):

> This is login.php file..and action of the form is also in the same file.Can this happen?

Yes

> if,then same login form should open if user submit the form

Not necessarily. In a system like this, the form data will be processed by server side code. The logic will probably be something like:

```
If it is a GET request, send the browser the form.

Otherwise, if it is a POST request, then check the form data:

    If it is valid login data, then: set a cookie to track the user and 
    tell the browser to get some other URL.

    Otherwise, the login data is wrong: populate the form with an error message
    and possibly default the values of the fields to the wrong data the user
    entered, then send the form to the browser.
```

Populating the form with the invalid data doesn't make much sense in a login form like this one, but it more useful in (for example) a registration form.

Who wants to retype all their personal data *again* just because the username they wanted is not available or they missed a field?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to send form to same file but it's not in good style. You would have to check if post data is available and display proper view based on that.

Better way to do it is just change the action of the form to point to another file and in that file handle login logic.

```
<form action="file.php" method="post" class="f-wrap-1">
```

Comment: or you can trigger an `$.ajax` call to check the credential on submit and not use `action` at all (but you have to understand javascript code)

Comment: "it's not in good style" — It is common practice and an excellent way of being able to redisplay the form with error messages if the user makes a mistake. It is not bad coding style.

Comment: its old not bad coding style. You can always make something work in many different ways. You choose the style

Comment: Thanks...But if i make another file say file.php(action file) ,then i have to retrieve the data from database.is this good to show it in public ( like in view source)?

Comment: You have retrieve login data from database no matter how you'll organize your code. Php code is not visible from source view in browser (it's executed on the server).